# iOS Objective-C: Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <GKModalRootViewController>

Tags: objective-c, ios, game-center, transition

I was hoping someone would be able to answer my question.

In my app I have a button you can press that takes you a leaderboard I have created. In the sandbox environment, the first time a user clicks on this the user is asked to sign in - with an existing account or a new account.

If a user clicks on use existing account, after verifying their username, password, GameCenter display name and so forth, when the screen closes to go back to the screen with the leaderboard button - none of the buttons will now respond. The user is forced to quit the app (and the instance through the double-click of the home button) and reopen the app, where now they can play as usual and even click on the leaderboard with no problems.

I was wondering why this was, and the only clue I seem to have is through the output screen in Xcode which says while running:

```
ClubHistory[4989:707] Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <GKModalRootViewController: 0x1bcd90>.
```

From looking up other questions it seems this might mean a clash of opening/closing views. But I don't really understand where I should implement this.

Part of the code which opens the leaderboard in the first instance is:

```
-(void)leaderboardViewControllerDidFinish:(GKLeaderboardViewController *)viewController
{
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

-(IBAction ) showLeaderboard
{
GKLeaderboardViewController *leaderboardController = [[GKLeaderboardViewController alloc]init];
if (leaderboardController != NULL)
    {
    leaderboardController.category = self.currentLeaderBoard;
    leaderboardController.timeScope = GKLeaderboardTimeScopeWeek;
    leaderboardController.leaderboardDelegate = self;
    [self presentModalViewController: leaderboardController animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Perhaps the alteration I need to make is made here.

I had a look online for similar problems to no avail. Does anyone know how I can solve this issue?

Thanks everyone,

Andy.

///// Quick edit: Just to clarify I have ARC turned on for my app.

Answer (score 0):

> [...] the first time a user clicks on this the user is asked to sign in - with an existing account or a new account

How are you presenting this interface for the user to sign in? Is it also a Modal View Controller? If this is the case, maybe you're not presenting and dismissing these two Modal View Controllers properly. From Apple's [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ModalViewControllers/ModalViewControllers.html):

> Any view controller object can present a single view controller at a time.

Try dismissing the View Controller with the sign in interface before presenting the `GKLeaderboardViewController`.